# Angular : Parent scope function not getting fired from directive button click

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call the parent scope's function from the directive. But it's not getting fired. Can any one point out what is it that I'm missing ?

Here is my directive code:

```
 .directive('myComp',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            vname:'&'
        }
    }
 });
```

Here is the view code:

```
    <my-comp vname="updateVal(val)">

      <input type="text" ng-model="nm">
      <button ng-click="vname({val:nm})">Save</button>

</my-comp>
```

And here is the controller code with the function:

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {

    $scope.iname = 'roy';
    $scope.updateVal = function(val){
        alert('hi');
        $scope.iname = val;
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if it is written under controller.

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='View1Ctrl'>
   <my-comp vname="updateVal(val)">
```

.....